# How to fix migration model 'id' field in Django 2.2?

Tags: python, django, django-models, orm, django-migrations

I have a Django model that does not contain a field for 'id' but in my MySQL instance from a previous migration it shows an 'id' field for some reason. I kept getting an error saying:

```
You are trying to add a non-nullable field 'id' to discussions without a default; we can't do that (the database n
eeds something to populate existing rows).
```

So I went and inspected my `models.py` file which has no 'id' field:

```
class Discussions(models.Model):

    #team_id = models.ForeignKey(Teams, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    login = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True)
    uid = models.PositiveIntegerField(primary_key=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True)
    body = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True)
    comments = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True)
    updated_at = models.CharField(max_length=21, null=True)
```

But it is showing up in my MySQL `describe` statement:

```
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id         | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| login      | varchar(30)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| comments   | varchar(30)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| updated_at | varchar(21)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| body       | varchar(500) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| title      | varchar(30)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

and when I dropped the table to try and re-sync the database I am getting an error saying that:

```
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: (1146, "Table 'my_project.app_discussions' doesn't exist")
```

Ideally I'd like to have some way of getting my `uid` variable in my view to actually load into my db instance where the `id` field is being represented.

```
        # tree->tuples->list of tuples
        json_tree = objectpath.Tree(data)
        login = tuple(json_tree.execute("$..login"))
        uid = tuple(json_tree.execute("$..id"))
        title = tuple(json_tree.execute("$..title"))
        body = tuple(json_tree.execute("$..body"))
        comments = tuple(json_tree.execute("$..comments_count"))
        updated_at = tuple(json_tree.execute("$..updated_at"))

        # took out `uid`
        parsed_list = list(zip(login, uid, title, body, comments, updated_at))

        # LOADING PHASE
        load_data = []

        # took out `u`
        for l, t, i, b, c, u in zip(login, uid, title, body, comments, updated_at):

            load_data.append(Discussions(l, t, i, b, c, u))

        Discussions.objects.bulk_create(load_data)
```

Why am I not able to migrate this new schema over to MySQL? Why is this `uid` field not being mapped via the ORM into the ID field after I had it before? Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

The `id` is primary key and it's must be not nullable.
As, you add `id` field nullable in previous migrations then you need to alter previous migration or simply add new field in model and run migrations again

```
id = models.IntegerField(null=False, primary_key=True)
```